# How to use Apple (in app purchases) in UIWebView?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to use Apple In App purchases from a UIWebView inside the application ?

Since i want to use a web view to load an external website and use in app purchases as payement method inside the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call Objective-C methods from UIWebView. This you can do by trapping your custom urls in the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method. As well, you can call JS methods in HTML from Objective-C code (`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`). Details are [here](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/).

I think it is possible to use Apple's InApp purchase from inside UIWebView, though it depends on your exact requirements. As long as you use Apple's payment gateway (so that they get their 30% cut :)) it's okay.

Comment: Thank a lot this is what i was looking for (call Objective-C methods from UIWebView) and the link you post was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it works that way. It's a Cocoa touch API and has to be called from a Cocoa object / controller.

It also uses delegates to communicate back with your app.

Also sounds like what you are trying to do is use the in app purchase as your payment system for a web app. Might be outside the terms of service of AppStore.

Try Google In App Payments?

Comment: You cannot use any other method for selling digital goods (that you can do with Apple's InApp purchase) from within a native app. That means even not from UIWebView which ia part of native app.