# In-app purchases with a WebView

Tags: ios

I am developping an iOS application from a webapp, and I am using a WebView (`UIWebView`). I would like to know if it is possible to do **in-app purchases** using a **WebView** ?

If yes, can you tell me how ?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383068/how-to-use-apple-in-app-purchases-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you app can present a ViewController , you can use `WebViewJavascriptBridge`

https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

It's can send Webview info to native as dictionary , so a ViewController can purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a function in ios app from web content action.The ios function will do inapp purchase.That is if your web content have a  buy button.Action for the button should be a link.check it from webview delegate method and do action for that.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I thought I had to make a native application from 0 because of the in app purchases !

Comment: ok.Do you need any clarification?

Comment: As I am a newbie in iOS developpement I just don't know how to implement in-app payment, but I am pretty sure it is not very complicated, so I will probably find it easily.